# Multiplying two 128-bit ints

Tags: c, integer-arithmetic

I'm trying to multiply two 128-bit integers in C.

Here is my algorithm:

Split the two 128-bit sequences into S1 and S2.

Then split S1 into S11 (front/higher half) and S12 (back/lower half) and split S2 into S21 (front/higher half) and S22 (back/lower half).

Multiply S12 by S22... = S1222.

Multiply S11 by S21... = S1121 and then bit shift it by multiplying it by 2^128

Combine S1222 and S1121 to be the front and back halves of a new array. Let's call it "Array1". The new array's length is twice as long as S1.

Then we have to multiply S12 by S21 and S11 by S22. I have multiplied these two to get S1221 and S1122, respectively (and bit-shifted them accordingly). Now I have to add them to Array1. This is the part where I'm asking for help. I'm not sure how to add these, one by one, to Array1. Keep in mind there may be a carry of 1 as you go bit by bit from 3/4 of Array1 to 1/4 of Array1, as this is the span where S1221 and S1122 need to be added.

My question is: How do I add dstM1 and dstM2 to the array d, which is already filled?

Comment: ... And your question is?

Comment: How to add dstM1 and dstM2 to the array d, which is already filled.

Comment: Why go through the effort to use `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` and then use an `unsigned` array[4] with values like `0xffffffffu`.  `unsigned` is only guaranteed to have the range 0 to 65535.  If you want want to use `unsigned`, 1) be ready for variant sizes, 2) assume min C spec range or 3) just use `uint32_t`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to interpret a[0..n] as a[0]*2^32n + a[1]*2^32(n-1) + a[2]*2^32(n-2) + .. + a[n-1]*2^32 + a[n]*2^0
That's how we treat decimal places.

Comment: Note that you can use the [Karatsuba trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#The_basic_step) to get down the number of recursive multiplications from 4 to 3 per subproblem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing your question: How can you add two arrays of (unsigned) integers propagating the carry.

```
uint16_t foo[4];  // 0000 aaaa FFFF cccc
uint16_t bar[4];  // dddd eeee FFFF 0000
```

The good point is that 'FFFF+FFFF+1' is simply (1)FFFF. Thus the carry can always be added in each word without producing an extra carry (as if the sum could be 20000).

Making a temporary sum: `sum = foo[3] + bar[3] + carry;` with carry being initially 0, either this sum produces a new carry, or not.

- Carry is produced from (A+B), if `(A+B) < A`
- When summing (A+B+c), the carry is produced if `((A + c) < A) || (((A + c) + B) < B)`

Another possibility is to calculate "multi-bit carry" by summing up several terms in columns, which occurs often in bignum multiplications:

```
            AAAA BBBB CCCC
       DDDD EEEE FFFF ....
  GGGG HHHH IIII .... ....
--------------------------
  col4 col3 col2 col1 col0
```

Now each column produces 32-bit or 64-bit result and a carry that doesn't necessarily fit a single bit.

```
uint32_t sum_low = carry_in_from_previous_column;
uint32_t sum_high = 0;

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     sum_low += matrix[i][column] & 0xffff;
     sum_high += matrix[i][column] >> 16;
}
sum_high += sum_low >> 16;    // add the multibit half carry

result = (sum_low & 0xffff) | (sum_high << 16);
carry_out = sum_high >> 16;
```

Comment: Fixed the formula. `(A+c)` produces a carry only if c=1 and A=FFFF; then the result is '0', but it's not a sufficient condition.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on gcc or clang you can use `__int128` and `unsigned __int128` directly.

Comment: I want to multiply the two ints without those. I want to use a divide and conquer algorithm as described above.

Comment: And if not using those compilers, then what?

Comment: I meant not using "those" with "those" being _int128 and unsigned _int128.

Comment: @thetypist That makes sense. You'll probably want to do it in straight assembler, though, as you'll have direct access to the overflow registers.

Answer (score 3):

You are stuck in an infinite loop because `i += 1/32` is the same as `i += 0`.

Also: note:`memcpy(&d[3l/2-i], dstM1, 1/8);` is `memcpy(&d[1-i], dstM1, 0);`