# 128x128 bit multiplication on for x86 CPU

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly, multiplication

In my application I need a fast 128x128-bit multiplication (result = 256 bit). Is there any x86 optimised library out there performing this operation?

Comment: Recetn GCC have `int128_t` so you might leverage on that

Comment: Yeah, but it does not support a 256-bit integer for the result.

Comment: How much fast is fast enough?

Comment: related: [Multiplying two 128-bit ints](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22085516/995714). You can also multiply 2 `int128_t`s to get the low 128 bits and then calculate the high bits manually

Comment: [C++ 128/256-bit fixed size integer types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5242819/995714)

Comment: With (Intel) CPUs supporting MULX, ADCX and ADOX instructions, [using separate carry chains](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/intel-technology/ia-large-integer-arithmetic-paper.html) should beat Toom-Cook(-2) up to a couple of words/limbs.

Answer (score 2):

There is GNU GMP library - https://gmplib.org/ which should have good optimized multiplications for long integers. It has benchmark https://gmplib.org/download/misc/gmpbench-0.2.tar.bz2 which can be used to test 128x128 case (multiply.c, args 128 128)

For fixed sizes you can try low-level interfaces of GMP - `mpn` https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html

> Function: `mp_limb_t mpn_mul (mp_limb_t *rp, const mp_limb_t *s1p, mp_size_t s1n, const mp_limb_t *s2p, mp_size_t s2n)`
>   Multiply {`s1p, s1n`} and {`s2p, s2n`}, and write the (`s1n+s2n`)-limb result to `rp`. Return the most significant limb of the result.
>
> The destination has to have space for `s1n + s2n` limbs, even if the product's most significant limb is zero. No overlap is permitted between the destination and either source.
>
> This function requires that `s1n` is greater than or equal to `s2n`.

For some special cases on haswell claimed speed is 1.57-1.8 cycles/limb ("Normally a limb contains 32 or 64 bits")
http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/gmp/mpn/x86_64/coreihwl/mul_1.asm#35

Comment: There is `mpn_mul_n` since both operands have the same size.

Answer (score 2):

If you need only a fast 128x128-bit multiplication than you can do this by yourself.

Under 32 bit CPU you need 16 (32*32 bit) multiplications and under 64 bit CPU 4 (64*64 bit) multiplications.

The algorithem under 32 bit CPU (using 32 bit multiplication) is:

Let's say that ABCD and EFGH present two 128 bit numbers and any letter present a 32 bit digit of 128 bit number.

```
ABCD * EFGH =  
  ABCD * E * 2^96 //Multiplication with 2^96 is 96 left shift or mov for 3 32bit digits 
+ ABCD * F * 2^64 
+ ABCD * G * 2^32 
+ ABCD * H
```

and where n is 32 bit digit.

```
ABCD * n =  
  A * n * 2^96 //Multiplication with 2^96 is 96 left shift or mov for 3 32bit digits
+ B * n * 2^64
+ C * n * 2^32 
+ D * n
```

Comment: Many ISAs provide widening multiplication (32x32 => 64-bits in a pair of registers), e.g. x86, ARM, and MIPS.  (Some stripped-down ARM cores only have narrow mul).  In C, compilers typically know how to optimize `a * (uint64_t)b` into a widening multiply.  (But the problem with C comes when you try to get the compiler to emit an `adc` add-with-carry)